# psql ruins my shell if I press Ctrl+C

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, terminal, psql

This is a bit of a weird one. If I start `psql` but then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when it prompts for a password, the program seems to exit, but I can't see what I type anymore even though I'm back in my shell. It's as if everything I type is getting hidden because it still thinks I'm typing my password.

The only solution for this that I've found is to start a new shell, which is fine, but not great. I'd love to understand what's happening here and how to fix it.

Comment: Try the `reset` command to reset your terminal

Comment: `psql` turned off the terminal's echo mode, and [`reset`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html#h3-reset---reinitialization) turned it back on.

Comment: Is this a bug in `psql` though? I know of no other program where this happens.

Comment: Most other programs catch the signal and cleanup properly.  Python seems to do this too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`reset`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html#h3-reset---reinitialization) often works, but is not a panacea.  For this case, only the terminal echo was disabled.  Other programs may modify the handling of carriage return, making it awkward to type "reset" (you can do that, but would have to type <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to end the line).

In other cases, because `reset` relies upon the *terminal description*, it may not reset *everything*.  Particular troublespots are (a) alternate character sets and (b) changes to the terminal's color palette.

- While [`ncurses`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) has many terminal descriptions which *do* reset the alternate character set, it is a common problem on Unix systems to *not* do this.
- Over the past few years, people have been using the xterm 256color sequences to set a color palette, but `reset` has no way to revert those to a default palette.

Aside from the terminal description part, `reset` performs a function similar to `stty sane`.